# How many months someone was there in that year in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

We consider this dataframe which represents contracts of workers. I would like to list how many months a worker worked for a certain year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame{'id': {0: 19019,
  1: 17160, 2: 21593, 3: 3146, 4: 21593, 5: 3146, 6: 22737, 7: 25311, 8: 25740,
  9: 3289, 10: 26312, 11: 28028, 12: 17017, 13: 27742, 14: 26884,
  15: 31174, 16: 31889, 17: 33319, 18: 35178, 19: 35464},
 'start_date': {0: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2016-09-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00'),     
  3: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00'),    
  5: Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2018-09-01 00:00:00'),      
  7: Timestamp('2018-09-01 00:00:00'),8: Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'),      
  9: Timestamp('1999-11-01 00:00:00'),10: Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'),      
  11: Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),12: Timestamp('2009-11-01 00:00:00'),      
  13: Timestamp('2019-09-01 00:00:00'),14: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'),      
  15: Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'),16: Timestamp('2020-04-14 00:00:00'),      
  17: Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'),18: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),      
  19: Timestamp('2021-03-08 00:00:00')},
 'end_date': {0: Timestamp('2017-01-31 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2018-07-31 00:00:00'),2: Timestamp('2017-02-28 00:00:00'),      
  3: Timestamp('2017-07-31 00:00:00'),4: Timestamp('2017-12-31 00:00:00'),      
  5: Timestamp('2017-12-31 00:00:00'),6: Timestamp('2021-12-31 00:00:00'),      
  7: Timestamp('2019-08-16 00:00:00'),8: Timestamp('2019-11-30 00:00:00'),      
  9: Timestamp('2022-12-31 00:00:00'),10: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'),      
  11: Timestamp('2021-02-28 00:00:00'),12: Timestamp('2022-10-31 00:00:00'),      
  13: Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'),14: Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'),      
  15: Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'),16: Timestamp('2021-06-30 00:00:00'),      
  17: Timestamp('2022-09-30 00:00:00'),18: Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'),      
  19: Timestamp('2022-03-07 00:00:00')}})
```

So if we consider 2020:

```
year = 2020
after = df.index[df.start_date.dt.year >= year] # Started late in that year
before = df.index[df.end_date.dt.year <= year] # Left early in that year

df['after'] = df.iloc[after].start_date.dt.month
df['before'] = df.iloc[before].end_date.dt.month
df = df.fillna(0)
df['months'] = 12
df['months'] -= df['after']
df[df.before > 0]['months'] -= 12 - df['before']
df = df.drop(['before', 'after'], axis=1)

dm = df[(df.start_date.dt.year <= year) & (df.end_date.dt.year >= year)]
dm
```

I get the list of workers that worked in 2020 for n months:

```
    id      start_date  end_date    months
13  22737   2018-09-01  2021-12-31  12.0
16  3289    1999-11-01  2022-12-31  12.0
17  26312   2018-10-01  2020-09-30  12.0
18  28028   2019-01-01  2021-02-28  12.0
19  17017   2009-11-01  2022-10-31  12.0
20  27742   2019-09-01  2022-02-28  12.0
21  26884   2020-03-01  2022-02-28  9.0
22  31174   2020-03-01  2022-02-28  9.0
23  31889   2020-04-14  2021-06-30  8.0
24  33319   2020-10-01  2022-09-30  2.0
```

Is there a better *pandaish* method to achieve the same?

(feel free to rename the question, I am sure it is terribly named)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 2 date ranges: first is the target period in `2020` with month frequency, second is for each row the period from `start_date` to `end_date` in month frequency.  Then find their common intersection months by [`np.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) and find the number of matching months by the length of the array of common months:

```
rng2020 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31', freq='M')
df['months'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(np.intersect1d(pd.date_range(start=x['start_date'], end=x['end_date'], freq='M'), rng2020)), axis=1)
df.loc[df['months'] !=0]
```

Result:

```
       id start_date   end_date  months
6   22737 2018-09-01 2021-12-31      12
9    3289 1999-11-01 2022-12-31      12
10  26312 2018-10-01 2020-09-30       9
11  28028 2019-01-01 2021-02-28      12
12  17017 2009-11-01 2022-10-31      12
13  27742 2019-09-01 2022-02-28      12
14  26884 2020-03-01 2022-02-28      10
15  31174 2020-03-01 2022-02-28      10
16  31889 2020-04-14 2021-06-30       9
17  33319 2020-10-01 2022-09-30       3
```

Comment: I get this warning : `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.` how to avoid it?

Comment: @nowox In general, you can make a copy of the dataframe by e.g. `df2 = df.copy()` before the line of code that got this warning, and then use the new `df2` for further processing. Of course, remember to amend the codes after this line to refer to this new `df2` instead.

Comment: @nowox  You can change my last line of code to eg. `df2 = df.loc[df['months'] !=0].copy()` and then use `df2` for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

One way via `np.select`:

```
year = 2020

condlist = [
    (df.start_date.dt.year < year) & (df.end_date.dt.year > year),
    (df.start_date.dt.year == year) & (df.end_date.dt.year == year),
    df.start_date.dt.year == year,
    df.end_date.dt.year == year,
]

choicelist = [
    12,
    df.end_date.dt.month - df.start_date.dt.month,
    12 - df.start_date.dt.month,
    df.end_date.dt.month,
]

df['work_hours'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

NOTE: drop the rows where work_hours are 0 if required.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
start = '1/1/2020'
end = '12/31/2020'

s = (df['end_date'].clip(upper = pd.to_datetime(end)) - 
     df['start_date'].clip(lower = pd.to_datetime(start))).floordiv(pd.to_timedelta(30,'d'))
df = df.assign(months = s.where(s.gt(0)))
```